# What is the easiest way to execute code based on the item selected in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView with two elements. I would like to execute different code based on the item that has been selected. Until now my code looks like this (but it is not working):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        View root = (View) listview.getParent();
        if (position == 1) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#133b96"));
        } else if (position == 2) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
        }
    }
```

I want to change the background color, and the color should be based on the selected item.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: why you require listview to show just two items, why don't you go for Two buttons?

Comment: @Nagaraj436 good question, actually I have several items, I put only two in my code not to make it too long :)

Comment: shouldn't position be 0 and 1 not 1 and 2?

Comment: @biddulph.r LOL that was it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    if (position == 1) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#133b96"));
    } else if (position == 2) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
    }
}
```

Just look at your `protected void onListItemClick()` methods for parameters `View v`. Which is a Selected list item's View. And if you want to change background color of ListView then use

`ListView l`.

something like,

```
if (position == 1) {
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#133b96"));
    } else if (position == 2) {
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
}
```

So you have to remove additional code from it to get it to work.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working, nothing happens when I click on a list item. Is it enough to write `position == 1`?

Comment: Yes, Actually you have to change color of Listview according to List Item selection which is just on Position basis.

Comment: I should have simply started counting from 0 :D

Comment: As its mentioned in your question. We just make correction over it. We don't know exactly about position.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch on the position.
A more OOP approach would be to use the tag property of view, and use it to store some runnable.

e.g.

```
item.setTag(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // run whatever code you want
    }
}
```

...

```
((Runnable)view.getTag()).run();
```

Comment: What about simply switching on the position? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
   ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(this, R.layout.lay_item, theObjects);
   myList.setAdapter(adapter);
   myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    MyClass item = (MyClass) adapter.getItem(position);
   }
  }
```